# Options for free (and preferably open source) speech to text library

Tags: java, python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Looking for a library (with Java or Python APIs) that converts speech to text. 100% accuracy is not an absolute requirement because I just need to run some experiments for a prototype. Ideally it should accept an input file (e.g., .wav) and return the output as text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Sphinx like kdazzle has suggested for you or you can also check out other java implementation [here](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapifaq.html#implementation).

For python library, check out [pyspeech](https://github.com/michaelgundlach/pyspeech) or [dragonfly](https://github.com/t4ngo/dragonfly). If the library can output the text, I think the library should be possible to print out the text into a file.

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good. It's made by the folks at Carnegie Mellon.

Comment: Thanks. I've already looked and implemented this this option. I'm looking for other options as well.